# Jgitflow maven plugin fails to execute

Tags: maven, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I am experimenting to use gitflow strategy for my project and for that I choose to use maven jgitflow plugin for release preparation. When I execute the "mvn jgitflow:release-start" command, the build immediately fails with below error.

I am using an apple MacBook with an Apple M1 Pro chip. Is this the reason for build failure? any help is appreciated.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start (default-cli) on project Test:Execution default-cli of goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/nq/ty3pk4nn3kbfwtzvxrl3j7gm0000gn/T/jna/jna5015757959737739854.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/nq/ty3pk4nn3kbfwtzvxrl3j7gm0000gn/T/jna/jna5015757959737739854.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/nq/ty3pk4nn3kbfwtzvxrl3j7gm0000gn/T/jna/jna5015757959737739854.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have (i386,x86_64,unknown), need (arm64e)))
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/external/atlassian/jgitflow/jgitflow-maven-plugin/1.0-m5.1/jgitflow-maven-plugin-1.0-m5.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/external/atlassian/jgitflow/jgit-flow-core/1.0-m5.1/jgit-flow-core-1.0-m5.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/3.7.1.201504261725-r/org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/javaewah/JavaEWAH/0.7.9/JavaEWAH-0.7.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.3/httpclient-4.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.4/httpcore-4.1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/servicemix/bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch/0.1.51_1/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch-0.1.51_1.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/external/atlassian/jgitflow/jgitflow-maven-api/1.0-m5.1/jgitflow-maven-api-1.0-m5.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jgit/org.eclipse.jgit.console/3.7.1.201504261725-r/org.eclipse.jgit.console-3.7.1.201504261725-r.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/jline/jline/1.0/jline-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.2/gson-2.2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom2/2.0.4/jdom2-2.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/guava-14.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-api-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/release/maven-release-manager/2.4/maven-release-manager-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/2.1/maven-invoker-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-manager-plexus/1.8/maven-scm-manager-plexus-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-api/1.8/maven-scm-api-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons/1.8/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1/jdom-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/jaxen/jaxen/1.1-beta-8/jaxen-1.1-beta-8.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy.jsch/0.0.7/jsch.agentproxy.jsch-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.49/jsch-0.1.49.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy.core/0.0.7/jsch.agentproxy.core-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna/0.0.7/jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/platform/3.4.0/platform-3.4.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy.sshagent/0.0.7/jsch.agentproxy.sshagent-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/Users/Testuser/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.7/slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]][ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why, but jgitflow under Mac M1 needs jna.

add in your pom in the jgitflow plugin this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
  <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
  <version>5.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```